# Use ascii code in from_addr to send email by smtplib

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, smtplib

I use `AWS` as an email server to send emails by `smtplib`. Unfortunately, when I set `from_addr` as in below, It does not work! It seems this char `ý` is not supported.

```
from_email = "Upmý  <mrab.m.72@gmail.com>"

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = email.header.Header(force_text(subject), 'utf-8')
msg['From'] = from_email
msg['To'] = addr
s = smtplib.SMTP(config['host'], config['port'])
s.sendmail(from_email, [msg['To']], msg.as_string())
```

I faced this error:

```
SMTPDataError: (554, b"Transaction failed: User name is missing: '=?utf-8?q?Upm=C3=BD_triko_=)
```

When I remove `ý` it works. Any comment or answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, in python3, a [Header](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/email.header.html#email.header.Header) object is needed to encode a `From` as `utf-8` (The same as you did for `Subject`):

```py
msg['From'] = email.header.Header(from_email, 'utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I change the msg['From'] and use this command `s.sendmail(msg['From'], [msg['To']], msg.as_string())` I got the error: `TypeError: object of type 'Header' has no len()`

Comment: It seems I should pass string for from_addr field

Comment: `smtpobj.sendmail(from_email, addr, msg.as_string())`

Comment: @MaryamAbdoli Just cast `msg` object.